# group and perform calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
ID BRAND_NAME PRICE COLOR ACTUAL PREDICTED MAPE ACCURACY
1   mjjk       657   Black  0     1         0    1
1   mjjk       657   Black  1     1         0    1
```

I want by dataset to be grouped by ID and have it like this:

```
ID BRAND_NAME PRICE COLOR ACTUAL PREDICTED MAPE ACCURACY
1   mjjk       657   Black  1    2         1    0
```

where Actual and Predicted columns has the sum of actual values of the particular ID and mape and accuracy are calculated using the sum of actual and predicted values like `MAPE=(Predicted-Actual)/Actual` and Accuracy is `1-MAPE`

am now stuck with how to group by id and get the corresponding values

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [121]: res = df.groupby(['ID', 'BRAND_NAME', 'COLOR'], as_index=False).agg({'PRICE':max, 'ACTUAL': sum, 'PREDICTED': sum})

In [123]: res['MAPE'] = (res.PREDICTED - res.ACTUAL).div(res.ACTUAL)
In [125]: res['ACCURACY'] = 1 - res.MAPE

In [126]: res
Out[126]: 
   ID BRAND_NAME  COLOR  PRICE  ACTUAL  PREDICTED  MAPE  ACCURACY
0   1       mjjk  Black    657       1          2   1.0       0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby.agg`. Group by `ID` and take the first of `'BRAND_NAME'`, `'PRICE'`, and `'COLOR'` and sum of `'ACTUAL'` and `'PREDICTED'`. Then do computations on the output dataframe to obtain `'MAPE'` and `'ACCURACY'` columns:

```
out = df.groupby('ID').agg({'BRAND_NAME':'first','PRICE':'first','COLOR':'first', 'ACTUAL':'sum', 'PREDICTED':'sum'}).reset_index()
out['MAPE'] = (out['PREDICTED'] - out['ACTUAL']) / out['ACTUAL']
out['ACCURACY'] = 1 - out['MAPE']
```

Output:

```
   ID BRAND_NAME  PRICE  COLOR  ACTUAL  PREDICTED  MAPE  ACCURACY
0   1       mjjk    657  Black       1          2   1.0       0.0
```